# derivative is positive but there is not any increasing neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

The book gives following propositions:

Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, let c be an interior point of A and let $f$ be differentiable at $c$. Then the following hold:

(1) If $f^{\prime}(c)>0$ there exists $\delta>0$, such that
$f(x)<f(c)$ if $c-\delta<x<c$, and $f(x)>f(c)$ if $c<x<c+\delta$

(2) If $f^{\prime}(c)<0$, then there exists $\delta>0$, such that
$f(x)>f(c)$ if $c-\delta<x<c$, and $f(x)<f(c)$ if $c<x<c+\delta$

After text assigns the following exercise:

Give an example of a differentiable function $f$, such that $f^{\prime}(0)>0$, but there exists no $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is strictly increasing in the interval $]-\delta, \delta[$

Which answer should be the function:
$$g(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
x+2 x^{2} \sin (1 / x) & \text { if } & x \neq 0 \\
0 & \text { if } & x=0
\end{array}\right.$$

I was confused. Doesn't it contradicts the above proposition?

Comment: What is $A$, exactly?

Comment: A is real interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Increasing" refers to all $x<y$ in $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$.  But (2) refers only to $x,c$.  Not enough to prove increasing.

---

Look at that example.  For all $x>0$ we have $g(0) < g(x)$; so (1) is correct.  But there exist $0 < x < y < \delta$ so that $g(x) > g(y)$; so $g$ is not increasing on $(-\delta,\delta)$.

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand could you explain a little bit

Comment: you mean the proposition tells about only the point and about its neighborhood ??

Comment: yeah I got it thank you a lot